# MySQLdb installer says that python 2.7 wasn't found in the registry

Tags: python, mysql, windows, python-2.7, installation

I am using Django and am in need of the MySQLdb package. When I download it and run the installer it says

> Python version 2.7 is required but it was not found in the registry

or something like that, and I can't go on in the installer any further.

I'm on windows 7 home premium 64 bit x86 if that matters. Thanks

Comment: Did you get a 64-bit MySQLdb installer?

Comment: +1 to BrenBarn, but also… did you use a 32-bit or 64-bit Python installer? You can use either on 64-bit Windows, but your MySQLdb has to be the same as your Python.

Comment: Also, assuming you actually have Python 2.7, how did you get it? (In particular, did you use the installer from python.org and leave all the checkboxes in the default state?)